# Async Task cannot access original thread

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have moved my code to an async task to perform an operation on the background thread. The code is below:

```
public class AsynTaskActivity  extends  AsyncTask<HashMap<String, Integer>, Void, Void>
{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(HashMap<String, Integer>... hashMaps)
    {

        HashMap<String, Integer> maps = hashMaps[0];
        //
        Set set = maps.entrySet();
        for (Object aSet : set)
        {
            Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) aSet;

            receiveBarcode(entry.getKey().toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

However, when running the code base. I encounter the following error:

```
Process: com.touchsides.checkout.debug, PID: 7447
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
 Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6556)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:942)
```

I would assume that the doInbackground is running on a separate thread and this error should not be encountered.

Comment: whats in receiveBarcode()? are you doing some UI updates in that?

Comment: put the ui codes inside a `runOnUiThread()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `AsyncTask` you can never perform UI interaction in `doInBackgound`, however you can still update your UI if you pass the progress or result in `onProgressUpdate` and `onPostExecute` respectively, and that's how you regain UI thread. You could try changing your `AsyncTask` to something like:

```
public class AsynTaskActivity extends AsyncTask<HashMap<String, Integer>, String, Object> {

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(HashMap<String, Integer>... hashMaps) {
        // non-ui thread
        HashMap<String, Integer> maps = hashMaps[0];
        Set set = maps.entrySet();
        for (Object aSet : set) {
            Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) aSet;
            publishProgress(entry.getKey().toString()); // onProgressUpdate callback
        }
        return null; // onPostExecute callback
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        // ui thread
        receiveBarcode(progress);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        // ui thread
    }
}
```

[AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) is well documented, you can read more about it online.

Comment: This is the correct way to do it. Do Non-Ui stuff in doInBackground methos and do all the UI update stuff in the remaining three methods.

Comment: @Aaron isn't the doInbackground a separate thread, and the UI thread to show the progress and leave the heavy lifting on the background thread.

Comment: @George Yes, you should do whatever that's considered heavy in `doInBackground`, then pass minimal data to `onProgressUpdate` or `onPostExecute` to update the UI, but remember do not call these methods manually. `AsyncTask` is one of Android class that allows you to perform tasks in background on a separate thread, and also able to take you back to UI thread.

Comment: @Aaron when you say do not call them manually, what do you mean by that?

Comment: @George That's in the documentation. If you want to receive callback in `onProgressUpdate` to perform UI update, then call `publishProgress` somewhere in `loadInBackground`. Likewise, if you want to receive callback in `onPostExecute`, then you have to wait for `loadInBackground` to return result.

Answer (score 2):

Use `runOnUiThread()` on a reference to an activity

Answer (score 0):

Override `onPostExecute()` method in your `AsyncTask` and do UI stuff there.

If you really want to do change UI in `doInBackground()` method then you can use a `Handler` to do that.